# Multiple select wheres vs one select where OR

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, select

I was just wondering which statement is more efficient. I am looping through a list of UUIDs (could be up to 40 UUIDs), and SELECTing every time. Instead, should I use:

```
     SELECT * FROM `player_table` WHERE `playeruuid`=uuid1 OR `playeruuid`=uuid2 OR `playeruuid`=uuid3;
```

Then loop through the result set?

Comment: You'd use `IN` in this case.

Comment: `uuid1` ,`uuid2`,... are these were string literals or columns ?

Comment: @Prdp String literals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `IN()` which has better performance:

```
 SELECT * FROM `player_table` WHERE `playeruuid` IN(uuid1,uuid2,uuid3);
```

Other then that, hard to say what is more efficient without testing it .

Comment: You might want to explain why.

Comment: `OR` is optimized into `IN`.  So (at least in the last few versions) there is no performance difference.  You can 'prove' this by doing `FLUSH STATUS; SELECT ...; SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Handler%';`